# WPF and ClickOnce: Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly WpfApplication1.exe

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce, manifest

I'm testing deployment of a dummy WPF browser application in Visual Studio 2010.

If I click on the localhost xbap it runs OK.

Then I publish it on a file server, \Bebrus1002\Intranet\it\ABS\WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap, but when I click on the deployed xbap I get this error:

```
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [1/06/2012 18:14:34] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (RefDefValidation)
    - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly WpfApplication1.exe.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeAsyncWorker()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve it by removing a leftover reference to another project.